# LogonUser call - does the user need login rights to that machine?

Tags: c#, window, webserver, pinvoke

I've had a hard time locating much information on this method and so I thought I'd ask out here and see if you wonderful people could help.

What we basically have is this  ...

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

if (LogonUser(AdminDevUser,
              AdminDevDomain, 
              AdminDevPassword,
              8, // LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT    
              0, // LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT    
              out token))
{
    wi = new WindowsIdentity(token);
    WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();
    blnFileExists = File.Exists(strFileName);
    wic.Undo();
    CloseHandle(token);
    return blnFileExists;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
    //Console.WriteLine("LogonUser() failed with error code " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

The person who wrote this is no longer here and so I'm trying to figure out what is needed to make this work.  My assumption is that the logonUser method just impersonates the given login information logging onto the network from that web server ... then any subsequent calls done after the Impersonate will be done as if that user was doing them instead of whoever is logged onto the web server.  Correct?

We get an error from the throw line that looks as follows:

> 87 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Exception: 87

Comment: Are you sure it already worked? 87 is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER ("The parameter is incorrect.").

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you are correct, you need WRM/WSM to do the same thing on a remote computer as the code does above.

For more details about the API you try to use above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"...You cannot use LogonUser to log on to a remote computer..."
and
"If (...)succeeds, you receive a handle to a token that represents the logged-on user. You can then use this token handle to impersonate (...)"

---

To test if a file exists (and reading it later, perhaps?) on a remote system I'd recommend sharing that file or it's containing folder, or using server-client connection (e.g. socketing).

The complex way to sort out the issue is with using Windows Remote Management. You can find a good starting point here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope this helps!